# Improve the time series model in python

Tags: time-series, python

I have the below data. This is data from 2019, where missing dates are '0'

```
DATE,value
01/04/2019,2
31/05/2019,1
04/07/2019,2
18/05/2020,1
05/06/2020,1
17/09/2020,1
06/10/2020,3
21/10/2020,42
26/10/2020,1
30/11/2020,1
02/12/2020,2
03/12/2020,1
12/12/2020,3
14/12/2020,1
15/12/2020,2
17/12/2020,1
24/12/2020,1
05/01/2021,1
13/01/2021,1
04/02/2021,2
18/02/2021,1
10/03/2021,1
01/04/2021,1
09/04/2021,1
25/04/2021,1
18/05/2021,1
19/05/2021,1
07/06/2021,1
30/06/2021,1
09/07/2021,1
15/07/2021,1
26/07/2021,1
27/07/2021,1
29/07/2021,2
06/08/2021,1
16/08/2021,1
17/08/2021,2
23/08/2021,1
24/08/2021,1
25/08/2021,1
28/09/2021,2
21/10/2021,1
15/02/2022,1
24/02/2022,2
18/03/2022,1
31/05/2022,1
```

I am trying to do forecasting for next two years. i tried ARIMA,AUTO ARIMA, holtsmethod and holts winter to do the forecast and non of them give satisfactory result.
I tried cumulating the value and then do the forecast, then the models will give a trend but without any patterns. How can I do forecast on such data?

Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 1):

First, your data seems to be count data, so rather than `auto arima`, you should use e.g. [tscount](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tscount/index.html). Second, you have huge gaps of missing data, which makes it unlikely that any time series model will succeed in obtaining some pattern. Third, if you nevertheless want to try it, you should not impute the missing data with 0 but rather with a count near the average.

It would of course be helpful to get more information about your data, but without that, I would first try proper imputation, aggregate the imputed data monthly, and then apply a time series model to this monthly time series, probably with seasonality.

Comment: what are your thoughts on of cumulating the data and then use forecast.. example: if original values are 1,0,0,1,1,1 .. after cumulating: 1,1,1,2,3,4 etc and then do forecasting?

Comment: That is what I meant by "aggregate and then apply a time series model". But you should impute before the aggregation.